# How to get typescript to recognize a custom action on the angular $resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-service

this is a sample use of the angular `$resource` in typescript. In this example I'm attempting to create an update action on the resource i've defined, exactly like it's done in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource. I'm also returning an instance `ng.resource.IResourceClass<IVenueResource>`

```
module app.common {
    interface IVenueService{

    }
    export interface IVenueResource extends ng.resource.IResource<app.domain.IVenue>{
      update(IVenue: app.domain.IVenue) : app.domain.IVenue;
    }

    export class VenueService implements IVenueService{
      static $inject = ["$resource", "url"];
      constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService, private url: URL_CONSTANTS){
      }

    getVenueResource(): ng.resource.IResourceClass<IVenueResource>{
      // Define custom action as IActionDescriptor
      var updateAction : ng.resource.IActionDescriptor = {
          method: 'PUT',
          isArray: false
      };
      return <ng.resource.IResourceClass<IVenueResource>>
      this.$resource(this.url.BASE_API+"/v1/venues/:id", {id: '@id'} ,{
        update: updateAction
      });
    }
  }
  angular
    .module("common.services")
    .service("venueService", VenueService);
}
```

now time to use the resource, the resource is defined by an interface implemented by my class. yet I still get an error, how do I get the typing dictionary to recognize the update method.

[image]

```
module app.Venue {

  interface INavigationScope{
    venueResource: ng.resource.IResourceClass<app.common.IVenueResource>;
  }

  class VenueListCtrl implements INavigationScope {
    venueResource: ng.resource.IResourceClass<app.common.IVenueResource>;
  }
  sample(){
    var updatedVenue =this.venueResource.update({id: 1, name: 'Amphitheather'},
       ()=> {});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soon realized that from this reference https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular-resource.d.ts#L85

I should be using `IResourceClass<IResource<T>>` to extend my interface, because `IResource<T>` does not have an option to add a custom method.

```
interface IResourceClass<T> {
        new(dataOrParams? : any) : T;
        get(): T;
        ...
}
```

Furthermore, when using the custom method, I needed to assign the correct declaration.

```
interface INavigationScope{ venueResource: app.common.IVenueResource; }
```

Returning an instance of `IVenueResourceClass` which is a child of `ng.resource.IResourceClass<ng.resource.IResource<app.domain.IVenue>>` but with the `update()` method.